# make a nested list using a for loop and random numbers

Tags: python, list, random, while-loop

I am looking to make a nested list. In each list I will have random numbers generated from 1 - 80 and 1000 lists. I have the random number part down, but can not make the nested list. this is what I have.

```
def lots_of_draws ():
    numbers_to_draw_from = list(range(1, 81))
    random_draws = sorted(random.sample(numbers_to_draw_from, k=20,))
    random_draws_list = []
    time_ = 0
    while time_ > 100:
        random_draws_list.append(random_draws)
        time_+=1
        print(time_)

    print(random_draws_list)
lots_of_draws()
```

expected [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,20,50,45,58,32,78,80,16],[another 20],[anoter 20],and so on for 100, or 1000]

I don't know what I doing wrong, any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Your `while` loop never runs, because `time_` is not `> 100` initially.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that your `while` loop will never run. You probably want `while time_ < 100` instead. You'll still not get the expected result after fixing that though, because on each iteration, you're appending the same list to `random_draws_list`. `random_draws` is only created once.

Possible fix:

```py
def draw_n(numbers, n):
    return sorted(random.sample(numbers, k=n))


def lots_of_draws():
    numbers_to_draw_from = range(1, 81)
    random_draws_list = []
    for time_ in range(100):
        random_draws_list.append(draw_n(numbers_to_draw_from, 20))
        print(time_)

    print(random_draws_list)
```

Comment: I was going to post something similar.  I suggested using a `for _cnt in range(100):` rather than the `while time_ < 100:`, simpler to understand.   Also, you don't need to have the list() the initial random variables.

Comment: Yes, this was simply the quickest solution to the problems in the original post. I'll update the answer to include both your points.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will also fix your problem.

```
from random import randint

def lots_of_draws():
    main_list = []
    for i in range(1000):
       nested_list = []
       for i in range(20):
           nested_list.append(randint(0,80))
       main_list.append(nested_list)
    return main_list
```

Comment: An explanation would be better than just a code dump.

Comment: Your solution introduces a common mistake when dealing with randomness.  With your method It is possible to get duplicate random numbers.  The method the OP choose would not create duplicates, since the numbers as selected from a pool of possibilities.  If these were a deck of playing cards, you solution could end up with five kings of ♠️'s.

Comment: Thank you so much this all really helped. Now on the next problem :-). I'll ask that as a separate question.  Once again thank you all.